# very basic VBA function not working

Tags: vba, excel

At first, I wanted to get myself some knowledge about VBA because it's used often at the company I recently started working. So I decided to do a [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_functions.htm) about it. I have some knowledge about vb.net from when I went to school.

I do know this is very basic and there is a built-in 'SUM function' in Excel.

While I'm trying to select the 2 cells with the numbers in does this error appear when I select the 2nd cell:
[image]
[image]
*(English version error message from the internet)*

The code I typed for the function:

```
Function fnSum(Num1 As Double, Optional num2 As Variant)
    If IsMissing(num2) Then
        fnSum = Num1 * Num1
    Else
        fnSum = Num1 * num2
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: In your picture I see that you placed a comma `,` after `B12`, with nothing else. If you are not going to include the Optional argument, then don't include the comma.

Comment: All you need is `=fnSum(B12)`.

Comment: the error appears right after I click or write down    C13

Comment: Where have you placed that code? It is supposed to be placed on a `Standard Module` like `Module1` etc.

Comment: Well the issue is, no one knows what C13 is

Comment: 'B12' is where the '2' is, 'C12' is where the '3' is. @K.Davis

Comment: @sktneer the code has been written on a standard module and is named Module1

Comment: Did you try referencing only one cell as I suggested? Did it work then? Other possibility is using comma if you use semi colon in the excel formulas.

Comment: When I used '=fnSum(B12)' it returned 4

Comment: @ThimoDemey In your region, in Excel, do you separate argument by commas (as you show) or should it be semicolons?  If semicolons, do that only on the worksheet.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld It has been solved by using semicolon instead of comma.

Comment: Good idea @RonRosenfeld, I can't get the code to error at all but does when I use a semi-colon

Comment: Seems to be the other way around for me, using semicolon works, normal comma causes it to an error.

Comment: @Davesexcel Whether to use a comma or semicolon **on the worksheet** depends on the `List Separator` symbol in your computer's `Windows Regional Settings` dialog. If you use the wrong one, you get spanked. Some have it set to comma, some to semicolon, and you can use others, if you want to customize.

Comment: Ya, I use commas, when I used semi-colon it failed, so I assumed commas was the problem for the OP like you suggested

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
Function fnSum(ByRef Num1 As Double, Optional ByRef num2 As Variant)
    If num2 = "" Then
        fnSum = Num1 * Num1
    Else
        fnSum = Num1 * num2
    End If
End Function
```

Worked for me perfectly

[image]

Comment: Make sure you type ; instead of ,

Comment: Using ; instead of , fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the default value of the optional parameter

```
Sub fnSum(ByRef Num1 As Double, Optional ByVal num2 As variant = "")
    If num2 = "" Then
        fnSum = Num1 * Num1
    Else
        fnSum = Num1 * num2
    End If
End Function
```